# WooCommerce - How to insert icons before delivery method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, icons, shipping-method

Good day,

Could anyone please help me how to insert icons before delivery method?

I use this filter

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 
function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) { 
   // Use the condition here with $method to apply the image to a specific method.      

   if( $method->method_id === "napobocce" ) {
       $label = "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922830.svg' style='height: 30px; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;' />".$label;
   } 
   if( $method->method_id == "zasilkovna" ) {
       $label = "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922830.svg' style='height: 30px; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;' />".$label;       
   }
   if( $method->method_id == "doprava>ceska-posta>16" ) {
       $label = "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922830.svg' style='height: 30px; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;' />".$label;       
   }
   if( $method->method_id == "doprava>geis>16" ) {
       $label = "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922830.svg' style='height: 30px; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;' />".$label;       
   }
   return $label; 
}
```

---

This works normally for local pickup and Zásilkovna, but not for the last two.

I found the id I have with them at the value "value" in the input. Would anyone know how to help me?

Or how to do this using CSS only?

Comment: I've answered your question, this should help you find the correct method ID and then apply it in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To found out the correct `$method->method_id` you could use

```php
echo 'DEBUG: method id = '. $method->method_id;
```

---

So you get

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {
    // Remove afterwards
    echo 'DEBUG: method id = '. $method->method_id;
    
    // Use the condition here with $method to apply the image to a specific method.      
    if( $method->method_id === "local_pickup" ) {
        $label = "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922830.svg' style='height: 30px; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;' />" . $label;
    } elseif( $method->method_id == "zasilkovna" ) {
        $label = "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922830.svg' style='height: 30px; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;' />" . $label;       
    }
    
    return $label; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You can use $method->instance_id instead which is always unique.